# Attempt by method 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.Utilities.get_IsPageEditor()' to access method 'Sitecore.Context+PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()' failed

Tags: glass-mapper

Just updated a simple instance of Sitecore 8.1 to 8.2, the actual solution contains a simple demo, some templates, items, nothing too complex. All went fine as I followed all the steps from the upgrade document but now when I try to get into Sitecore I get the following:

> Attempt by method 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.Utilities.get_IsPageEditor()' to
>   access method 'Sitecore.Context+PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()' failed.

Is there a fix for this error somewhere? from the details below it seems to be from Glass and not Sitecore or my code.

[image]

**EDIT:**

After I removed all Glass packages from packages folder, removed entries from `packages.config`, removed all configs and then reinstalled a clean version of `Glass.Mapper.SC` and Glass.Mapper.Sc.MVC-5 via nuget on my solution now I get:

> Could not resolve type name:
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModelFromView,
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

[image]

I checked with dotPeek and indeed there isn't such method, but not sure why then there is this entry in Glass config:

```xml
<mvc.getModel>
        <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromItem, Sitecore.Mvc']"  type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc"/>
        <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromItem, Sitecore.Mvc']"  type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModelFromView, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc"/>
</mvc.getModel>
```

Then if I remove this again from config I get another error:

> Method not found: 'Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreContext
>   Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreContext.GetFromHttpContext(System.String)'.

Did anyone managed to have Glass working on a Sitecore 8.2 solution? I am not sure what else can I do to make it work fine.

My package entries:

```xml
 <package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc" version="4.2.1.188" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core" version="4.2.1.188" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc-5" version="3.3.1.48" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.config:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <settings></settings>
  <pipelines>
    <mvc.getModel>
      <processor type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc" />
    </mvc.getModel>
  </pipelines>
</sitecore>
```

Glass.Mapper.Sc.config:

```xml
<sitecore>
  <settings></settings>
  <pipelines>
    <mvc.getModel>
      <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromItem, Sitecore.Mvc']"  type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc" />
      <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.GetModel.GetFromItem, Sitecore.Mvc']"  type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModelFromView, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc" />
    </mvc.getModel>
    <getChromeData>
      <processor type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.GetChromeData.EditFrameBuilder, Glass.Mapper.Sc" patch:before="processor[1]" />
    </getChromeData>
  </pipelines>
  <events>
    <event name="publish:end">
      <handler type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Events.PublishEnd.GlassCacheClear, Glass.Mapper.Sc" method="ClearCache" />
    </event>
    <event name="publish:end:remote">
      <handler type="Glass.Mapper.Sc.Events.PublishEnd.GlassCacheClear, Glass.Mapper.Sc" method="ClearCache" />
    </event>
  </events>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Do you reference the correct Sitecore.Kernel.dll and have you updated Glass to its latest version?

Comment: Yes, all references are good. Checked also the version and it's the latest 4.2.188 on all 3 dlls (Glass.Mapper.dll, Glass.Mapper.Sc.dll, Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.dll) so not sure where the problem is.

Comment: Just to be sure: have you also checked the versions of the files in the website's bin folder?

Comment: Yes, my first comment was for the bin versions in the website. So it's not from the dlls version.Sadly not from there.

Comment: Did you upgrade your Glass nuget references, or did you remove them and then re-add them?

Comment: @jammykam yes, I did that now and getting a lot of other errors. Please see the new edit on the question.

Comment: I could reinstall via nuget

Comment: Make sure you have deleted all the standard Glass configs and DLLs from your deployed website first, then try to do a republish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're updating Glass Mapper at the same time, but I don't believe the Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc-5 package is required as of v4 (Apr 2015).

If you have a look at the [v4 release notes](http://www.glass.lu/Blog/GlassV4) they have simplified things down to one Nuget package: Glass.Mapper.Sc, which also includes the .Mvc dll that you require.  If your Nuget package install doesn't add it automatically, you can find it at `<your project>\packages\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Core.4.2.1.188\lib\Mvc5x\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc.dll` (where Mvc5x is the version of MVC you are using).

I have Glass Mapper working in 8.2, however when I installed the .Mvc-5 Nuget package you mentioned, I can replicate your `Could not resolve type name: Glass.Mapper.Sc.Pipelines.Response.GetModelFromView` issue.

If you can't get your project running without this .Mvc-5 Nuget package (you should be able to) let us know what appears to be missing / broken.

Comment: You are right. Mike Edwards helped me a few days with this problem but I  forgot to update this. He said exactly the same thing, I was using also the MVC package and I shouldn't have so I removed it and works perfectly now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use latest version of glass mapper: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Glass.Mapper.Sc/4.2.1.188 with Sitecore 8.2

In the new version you have:

```cs
 namespace Glass.Mapper.Sc
 {
   public class Utilities : Glass.Mapper.Utilities
   {
       public static bool IsPageEditor
       {
           get
           {
              return Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor;
           }
       }
    }
}
```

`Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor.IsPageEditor` is private now, and it was changed with `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor.IsExperienceEditor`.

Comment: I am using the latest version dlls from nuget but this doesn't help.

Comment: Your solutuon is not using the right version of Glass for 8.2 if it is trying to call IsPageEditor. I would double check that your references are correct.

Comment: @PeteNavarra I just did, and the versions were ok, but to be sure I reinstalled it from nuget and now I am getting other errors. (see latest edit on the question).

Answer (score 1):

The above answers didn't help me here. When I reflected out `IsPageEditor` for 4.2.188 it still used `IsPageEditor` not `IsExperienceEditor`. Looking at the source code it seems to depend on how the assembly is built:

```
public class Utilities : Mapper.Utilities
{

    public static bool IsPageEditor
    {
        get
        {
#if SC82
            return Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditor;
#else
            return Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor;
#endif
        }
    }
    public static bool IsPageEditorEditing
    {
        get
        {
#if SC82
            return Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing;
#else
            return Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing;
#endif
        }
    }
...
```

[image]

It's unclear from the NuGet package what version each build is for. When I upgraded from `4.2.188` to `4.2.189` the assembly contained the correct version. Making my think that this is built for SC 8.2 as opposed to 8.1. Bascially it looks like a build mistake to me.