# Sitecore 8.1 to 8.2 Glass Mapper Related Error?

Tags: glass-mapper, upgrade

I am attempting an update from Sitecore 8.1 Update 1 to 8.2 Update 2 and after running the update package and and showing now errors on the update, I am getting the below error after logging in.

I suspect it could be my version of glass mapper as I am running version v4.0.30319 and I have seen a few people suggest to others to update glass, but those people also said that the update didn't fix the error or simply gave them a new one.

If it is glass that needs to be updated is it simply of matter of updating all the references in each project?

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean PageMode.get_IsPageEditor()'.]
   Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.Initiate(IDependencyResolver resolver) in c:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\8567e2ba106d3992\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:109
   Foundation.Multisite.Services.MultisiteService..ctor() in C:\gnca\Foundation\Multisite\code\Services\MultisiteService.cs:30
   Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.Assets.GetPageRendering.AddAssets..ctor() in C:\gnca\Foundation\Multisite\code\Pipelines\Assets\GetPageRendering\AddAssets.cs:30

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +438
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +119
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +117
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, Boolean assert) +68
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetObjectFromType(XmlNode processorNode) +91
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipelineFactory.GetProcessorObject(XmlNode processorNode) +145
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CoreProcessor.GetMethod(Object[] parameters) +143
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +465
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args) +195
   Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline(String pipelineName, TArgs args, Func`2 resultGetter) +161
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.GetPageView() +293
   Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.PageContext.get_PageView() +31
   Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreController.GetDefaultAction() +26
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +385
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() +385
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c() +38
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PageMode.IsPageEditor` property is no longer there in Sitecore 8.2.

It looks like the version of Sitecore Glass Mapper you're using was compiled against an older Sitecore version.

See the exception you have. It tries to access `PageMode.IsPageEditor` in `Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.Initiate` method.

You definitely need to upgrade to the newer Glass version.

Comment: See also: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/125/attempt-by-method-glass-mapper-sc-utilities-get-ispageeditor-to-access-metho